# django 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error ,for forms.py

Tags: python, django

I just create a forms for user register
The code is here

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model



def lowercase_email(email):
        """
        Normalize the address by lowercasing the domain part of the email
        address.
        """
        email = email or ''
        try:
            email_name, domain_part = email.strip().rsplit('@', 1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            email = '@'.join([email_name.lower(), domain_part.lower()])
        return email

class SignupForm (forms.ModelForm):

    username =forms.CharField( 
        label='username',required=True,max_length=20,min_length=3)
    email = forms.EmailField( 
        label='email',required=True)
    password =forms.CharField( 
        label='pssword',required=True,max_length=20,min_length=6,widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password= forms.CharField(
        label='confirm_email',required=True,max_length=20,min_length=6,widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("username","email","password","confirm_password",)




    def clean(self):

        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data["confirm_password"]
        if password and password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("password not same")
        return password
```

and the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect,render
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect,Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from sns.accounts.forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=SignupForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            UserModel=get_user_model()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user=UserModel.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)

            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form=SignupForm(auto_id=True)
    return render_to_response('signup.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Once I test it , it shows error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Then I  remove the method clean from the forms.py , then everything works well

I do not know where is the problem .As I have just written the same code from others for the clean method.

Comment: Please, post the whole traceback for your error

Comment: Like @sk1p said, without more details about the error, it's hard to give you any help. The traceback will allow others to see where the error happens and the path the code takes to get there. Right now all we know is that an exception is being raised somewhere in code that you haven't provided, probably because it's inside a function you're calling.

Comment: You are suppose to return cleaned_data for def clean(self)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the call to super's clean() at the start of your clean().

`cleaned_data = super(SignupForm, self).clean()`

The error message seems to indicate that cleaned_data is a string and not a dictionary; it might help to print cleaned_data to see what it is.

Answer (score 4):

change `clean(self)` to `clean_confirm_password(self)`

or

return `cleaned_data` for `def clean(self)`
since clean def expects a dictionary and you are providing a string in form of password variable.

Comment: thanks,it works.
can you tell me why i can not use clean_password(self)
when i use this ,it show error

Comment: Because clean_password(self) is called before clean_confirm_password(self) (as is it declared first in your form), so clean_password won't yet have the value of clean_confirm_password in its cleaned_data dictionary.